# Add to polynomial equation in link list

Tags: c++

I want to add together two polynomial equations that are stored in a link list. If the power is same, then the coefficients with like powers are added. The code responsible for adding coefficients is working within this case. However, if the powers are not the same, then I run into an issue. How should I address it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct poly1
{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    poly1 *Next;
};

struct poly2
{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    poly2 *Next;
};

struct result
{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    result *Next;
};

poly1 *P1Head = NULL,*Ptr1=NULL;
poly2 *P2Head = NULL,*Ptr2 = NULL;
result *RHead = NULL,*PtrR = NULL;

void Display();
result *sorting(result *head);

void Insert_Poly1()
{
    int cofficient, power, n;
    cout << "\nEnter polynomial equation 1 " << endl;
    cout << "Eneter size of node : ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        P1Head = new poly1;
        cout << "\nEnter cofficient : ";
        cin >> cofficient;
        cout << "\nEnter power : ";
        cin >> power;
        P1Head->coff = cofficient;
        P1Head->pow = power;
        P1Head->Next = Ptr1;
        Ptr1 = P1Head;
    }
}

void Insert_Poly2()
{
    int cofficient, power,n;
    cout << "\nEnter polynomial equation 2 " << endl;
    cout << "Enter size of node : ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        P2Head = new poly2;
        cout << "\nEnter cofficient : ";
        cin >> cofficient;
        cout << "\nEnter power : ";
        cin >> power;
        P2Head->coff = cofficient;
        P2Head->pow = power;
        P2Head->Next = Ptr2;
        Ptr2 = P2Head;
    }
}

void Result()
{
    poly1 *Temp1 = P1Head;
    poly2 *Temp2 = P2Head;
    while (Temp1 != NULL && Temp2 != NULL)
    {

        if (Temp1->pow == Temp2->pow)
        {
        RHead = new result;
        RHead->coff = Temp1->coff + Temp2->coff;
        RHead->pow = Temp1->pow;
        RHead->Next = PtrR;
        PtrR = RHead;
        Temp1 = Temp1->Next;
        Temp2 = Temp2->Next;
        }

        else if (Temp1->pow > Temp2->pow)
        {
            RHead = new result;
            RHead->coff = Temp1->coff;
            RHead->pow = Temp1->pow;
            RHead->Next = PtrR;
            PtrR = RHead;
            Temp1 = Temp1->Next;
        }
        else if (Temp2->pow > Temp1->pow)
        {
            RHead = new result;
            RHead->coff = Temp2->coff;
            RHead->pow = Temp2->pow;
            RHead->Next = PtrR;
            PtrR = RHead;
            Temp2 = Temp2->Next;
        }

    }


    Display();
}


void Display()
{
    result *ptr;
    ptr = RHead;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->coff << "X^" << ptr->pow << " + ";
        ptr = ptr->Next;
    }
    cout << " ";
}

int main()
{
    Insert_Poly1();
    Insert_Poly2();
    Result();
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining three structures that have exactly the same layout? You shouldn't. define the structure *once* and instantiate as many of it as you want. This way you wont need to duplicate your code. Besides, since you're writing C++ code, so OOP, make the functions that work on a structure "member methods" of the structure.

Comment: It seems like a homework question so I won't write any code for you. However, you should focus more on the analysis of the different cases. For example, if the first polynomial is longer than the second one what should you do? (your while loop does not cover this case).